# Foreach-loop for Array, which got via AJAX-query

Tags: javascript, ajax, foreach, iteration

I have the JS-code:

```
$("#select_bank").change(function () {
  selected_bank = $("#select_bank option:selected").text();

  $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: 'html',
    data: {
      selectedBank: selected_bank
    },
    url: '<?= base_url() . 'atm/select_region'; ?>',
    success: function (list_regions) {
      foreach(keyVar in list_regions) {
        alert(list_regions[keyVar]);
      }
    }
  });
});
```

On callback "succes"s I get the array from server's script - in alert I see the "Array" - so I want to iterate via this array on client-side like I coded above, but when doing I get the error in console - "var keyVar is not defined". As I understand I need to typecast the `list_regions` param as array or some another way to fix it. Please, how to make it better?
Thanks!

upd: [image]

Comment: Try changing 'foreach' to 'for'

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Javascript doesn't have `foreach` construction. Use `$.each` method of jQuery

Comment: Eugene is trying to use a JavaScript construct, and you jumped to telling him the jQuery solution. Just because Eugene is already using jQuery is not a good reason to advocate that they overlook the language's built-in construct.

Comment: @Mythril, but `$.each()` is much more userful in this case

Comment: Exactly how is it more useful?

Comment: Please, don't argue. Just I'd like to stream to use the pure JavaScript instead of Jquery to make some simple actions, when it's possible in rather simple way)

Comment: @Daniil, both of which are available in a for..in looop

Comment: @Mythril `each()` just gives clear and readable interface. That's pretty good when you think beautiful is better than ugly.

Answer (score 6):

If I am right you cannot transform the foreach loop into jquery in that way.

You should use .each to iterate the values

```
$.each(list_regions, function(index, value) {
  alert(value);
});
```

You can find more information [here](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/).

Comment: Thanks for propose, but it works as I've mentioned at my first comment - "Seems to be I have the trouble on my server's script: I get the sequense of alerts with the letters "A","r","r","a","y" and not the value's of array ?"

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$("#select_bank").change(function(){
    // The following line was missing a var declaration,
    // Making it an implicit global
    var selected_bank = $("#select_bank option:selected").text();

    $.ajax({
        type:'POST',
        dataType:'html',
        data: { selectedBank: selected_bank },
        url:'<?=base_url().'atm/select_region'; ?>',
        success:function(list_regions){
            var keyVar;
            for(keyVar in list_regions) {
                if (list_regions.hasOwnProperty(keyVar)) {
                    alert(list_regions[keyVar]);
                }
            }
        }
    });

});
```

Comment: Seems to be I have the trouble on my server's script: I get the sequense of alerts with the letters "A","r","r","a","y" and not the value's of array ?

Comment: My guess would be that base_url() is returning a PHP array which is being cast to a string as "Array", which is then being iterated over letter by letter in JavaScript

Comment: I've updated the post to show what I get on JS-script. But to do it - I've made the dirty trick in CodeIgnater, but I really want to avoid such bad way...

Answer (score 0):

Use `$.each` method of jQuery, not used foreach.

```
$.each(res.keyVar, function(index, row) {
   alert(row);
});
```